# Is this true? An element which is not contained in a maximal ideal.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$a \notin M$ : maximal ideal of a ring $R$ $\Rightarrow$ $M+Ra=R$

I tried some my attempts but nothing was useful, can anybody help me?

add: My attempt was, for any $r \in R$, to construct an element $m$ of $M$ such that for some $b \in R, m+ba=r$ but I failed. I forgot what a maximal ideal was.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, $M+Ra$ is an ideal and properly contains $M$

Comment: Word to the wise: if you say "I tried some attempts" and don't mention what any of them are, you immediately lose most of your credibility. It's especially unbelievable in a case like this, where there is apparently only one thing to try. If instead you had included your work on honest attempts, even if they didn't work, even for such a simple question, you would have some credibility.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $R$ is commutative, then $M+Ra$ is an ideal. Besides, it contains $M$. But $M+Ra$ cannot be a proper ideal, since $M$ is a maximal ideal. Therefore, $M+Ra=R$.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, with $a\not \in M$, then $M+Ra=\langle M\cup \{a\}\rangle$. That is, it is the ideal generated by $M$ and $\{a\}$. $M$ is maximal, so that since $M+Ra\supsetneq M$, we have that $M+Ra=R$.